# knockout with ASP.Net MVC - data mapping issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

My view Model looks like this -

```
class ParentVM
{
    public List<Level1ChildVM> Level1Children();
    public class Level1ChildVM
    {
        public string Name;
        public Level2ChildVM Level2Child;
        public Class Level2ChildVM { .. level2 child properties goes here }
    }
}
```

In my view, i iterate through the Level1Children collection using foreach binding in virtual element -

js code -

```
 dataService.getData(function (data) {
        //bind data to form elements
        myVM = ko.mapping.fromJS(data);

        ko.applyBindings(myVM);
    });
```

The problem that i am facing is that the properties from level1ChildVM is getting displayed in the view. But the properties from level2 child is not getting displayed.
I also tried using with binding but id doesnt work.

Am i applying the bindings correctly?
Please help.

Comment: how did you declare your observable view models?

Answer (score 0):

Your js code is like this

```
Level1ChildMain = ko.observable({ arrayList: [{ id: 1, Name: "AA" }, { id: 2, Name: "BB" }, { id: 1, Name: "CC"}], single: { id: 10, Name: "Outer"} });
```

Your Html is like this

```
<div>
    <br />
    <div data-bind="foreach : Level1ChildMain.arrayList">
        <div>
            <label data-bind="value : id"></label>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <br />
    <div data-bind="with : Level1ChildMain.single">
        <div>
            <label data-bind="value : id"></label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also You can refer this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/HkQkc/51/) for two level model binding